# Generated SHA256 value is different from the expected SHA256 value

Tags: bash, encryption, cryptography, sha

The following steps are to be performed:

1. Do base64 decode on ASCII value.
2. To 'chirp' append the decoded value.
3. Generate sha256 on the "chirp<decoded_value>"

```
    #!/bin/sh
    a=$(echo MDkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDIgADAoR0WUZBTAkZv0Syvt+g5wGpb/HYHh22zAxCNP+ryTQ=|base64 -d)
    b="chirp$a"
    echo $b
    echo -n $b | sha256sum
```

I am getting a value of:
f62e19108cfb5a91434f1bba9f5384f9039857743aa2c0707efaa092791e4420

But the expected value is:
6a29cb4....

Am I missing anything?

Comment: are you sure that you're following the instructions correctly? I'd interpret _appending_ as adding something as a suffix, that would mean `b=${a}chirp` .

Comment: @lab9 I edited my post. I meant adding 'chirp' as a prefix.

Comment: Note that you've used the "bash" tag but your program is a standard Bourne shell script. @lab9's answer is correct but is based on bash. You'll have to change your first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For binary data, as the base64-decoded data that your dealing with, I would not rely too much on `echo`, but just pipe the stuff, like this:

```
<<<'MDkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDIgADAoR0WUZBTAkZv0Syvt+g5wGpb/HYHh22zAxCNP+ryTQ=' base64 -d | cat <(echo -n chirp) - | sha256sum
```

That gives me the result that you expect, *6a29cb438954e8c78241d786af874b1c7218490d3024345f6e11932377a932b6* .
Here, `cat` gets two file descriptors as arguments, the first one streaming the word "chirp" and the second one forwarding the stdout of the previous command (`base64 -d`)

Comment: The actual problem is the NUL character (```\0```) provided by the base64 decoding. A NUL character is understood as a string terminator in C programs like the Bourne shell and should not be used in string variables or program arguments. ```(echo -n chirp; base64 -d) <<< '...base64.string...' | sha256sum``` might be clearer BTW.

Comment: Also I have to implement in this in c code. Currently, I am able to correctly convert to base64. But to generate sha256 on the decoded value, we are using hmac_sha256() from [link](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/wpa/src/crypto/). hmac_sha256() has a key parameter as well. How do I use this function to generate the SHA256. Thanks